# How can I get row index in sql

Tags: sql, jdbc

Table Contents are:

```
|Emp_ID |  Name |
|-------|-------|
|1      |  xyz  |
|23     |  pqq  |
|22     |  wdd  | 
|12     |  fdv  |
```

Here I want the row index where Emp_ID is greater than 15.
Result should return 2 and 3

Comment: SQL tables are modeled as _unordered_ sets.  Therefore, there is no implicit "row index" as you refer to it.  The only order which exists in your result set is that defined by the ordering of one or more columns.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I am using a csv file to retive data from, is there any way to get row index in this case

Comment: @phanikumar: the only reliable way to get a "row index" is to create an additional column and populate that column with the line number from the CSV file when you import it.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  You can often add an identity or autoincrement column to the table as you load it.

Comment: If it is purely about the row index in the current result set, you can use [`ResultSet.getRow()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getRow()).